# How to make {value,array[i]} object pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving from backend side object which is formulated like:

```
[
  {value: 'FIRST', AvailableValues[{code: "one"},{code: "two"}]},
  {value: 'SECOND', AvailableValues[{code: "one"},{code: "two"}]
]
```

My question is how to map through this object to create pairs like

```
[{value: "FIRST", code:"one"}, 
{value: "FIRST", code:"two"},
{value: "SECOND", code:"one"},
{value: "SECOND", code:"two"}]
```

Thanks

I tried combination of javascript predefined methods like double map, keyed search and so on, but it resulted with errors

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: your initial data is an object or an array?

Comment: Hey can you share the response from the backend, as what you shared doesn't provide clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `reduce` function

Also, your initial data should be an array because if it's a object, then it should contains key with values

```js
const list = [
  {value: 'FIRST', AvailableValues:[{code: "one"},{code: "two"}]},
  {value: 'SECOND', AvailableValues:[{code: "one"},{code: "two"}]}
]

const result = list.reduce((acc,item) => {
  const res = item.AvailableValues.map(i => ({value: item.value, code: i.code}))
  
  return [...acc,...res]
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Sachila, this is the most elegant and working solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,  Assuming that you receiving array of object from backend

```
let result = [];
yourObject.forEach((x)=>{
    x.AvailableValues.map((innerItem)=>{ 
        result.push({value:x.value, code : innerItem.code})
    });
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? "Try this" is never a good answer.

Comment: @Andy yes, without testing I never post Ans. Title may wrong but it is tested

Comment: Thanks Jaydip, this approach work also!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `map` here if you're not going to return anything from it. `forEach` would be more appropriate.

Comment: correct, will keep note

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here gets the job done. For completion here is an approach using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) combined with an inner [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data  =[
  {value: 'FIRST', AvailableValues:[{code: "one"},{code: "two"}]},
  {value: 'SECOND', AvailableValues:[{code: "one"},{code: "two"}]}
]

const res = data.flatMap(({value,AvailableValues}) => AvailableValues.map(({code}) => ({value,code})))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks allot. I never worked with flatMaps, do you know are there benefits of using this approach - like a better performance impact or similar?

Comment: it is equivalent to calling `map` and then after that `flat`. you may get an idea from reading the first paragraph https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var response = [{
            value: 'FIRST', AvailableValues: [{ code: "one" }, { code: "two" }]},{
            value: 'SECOND', AvailableValues: [{ code: "one" }, { code: "two" }]}
    ];
    
    var output = [];
    
    response.forEach(function(o) {
        o.AvailableValues.forEach(function(oo) {
            var t = {
                value: o.value,
                code: oo.code
            };
            output.push(t);
        })
    });
    
    console.log(output);
```